# GLTF Loader Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: clipObject is undefined

Tags: three.js, gltf

I want to load `.glb` models using ThreeJS as done [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/080klxk0l), I'm using `webpack v5` bundler, and I have changed the code from the upper link to adapt to the new imports:

```js
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";

import BasePlate from "../assets/glb/BasePlate_16x16.glb";
import Lego_2x2 from "../assets/glb/Lego_2x2.glb";
import Lego_2x4 from "../assets/glb/Lego_2x4.glb";
...
    const parrotPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 2.5);
    loader.load(
        BasePlate,
      gltf => onLoad(gltf, parrotPosition),
      onProgress
    );
  
    const flamingoPosition = new Vector3(7.5, 0, -10);
    loader.load(
        Lego_2x2,
      gltf => onLoad(gltf, flamingoPosition),
      onProgress
    );
  
    const storkPosition = new Vector3(0, -2.5, -10);
    loader.load(
        Lego_2x4,
      gltf => onLoad(gltf, storkPosition),
      onProgress
    );
  }
...
```

Now when I try to load the models I get the error:

> `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: clipObject is undefined`

You can find the models, the source code, and the config files [here](https://github.com/bhomaidan1990/JS_Tutorial/tree/main/threejs_webpack). The js code is [here](https://github.com/bhomaidan1990/JS_Tutorial/blob/main/threejs_webpack/src/js/glbLoad.js).

##### Can you please tell me how to render these `.glb` models correctly? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work since you try to play animations although your glTF assets are static. I suggest you update `loadModels()` and remove the usage of `AnimationMixer` *or* you implement it conditionally like so:

```js
if (result.animations.length > 0) {

    const mixer = new AnimationMixer(model);
    mixers.push(mixer);

    const animation = result.animations[0]; // pick first animation
    const action = mixer.clipAction(animation);
    action.play();
}
```